# How to create sticky header with flexbox and REACT

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I have created a header component in REACT and the Header uses flexbox for layout. Now I need to make the Header stick. I tried using position: fixed but that messes up the flexbox styling. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can solve this?

The code is shown below. The height of the header varies depending on whether mobile menu is displayed or not.

Thanks.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Logo from './Logo'
import logo from '../images/transparent.png';
import MenuItem from "./MenuItem";
import MenuItemBurger from "./MenuItemBurger";

class Header extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.headerStyle = {
            height: 'auto',
            padding: 10,
            display: 'flex',
            justifyContent: 'space-between',
            zIndex: 10,
            backgroundColor: 'white'
        };

        this.burgerMenuIconStyle = {
            color: '#757c8b',
        };

        this.mobileMenuStyle = {
            zIndex: 20,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
        };

        this.state = {
            windowWidth: window.innerWidth,
            mobileNavVisible: false,
            navItems : [
                {text: 'Home', selected: true, id:'home'},
                {text: 'Our Services', selected: false, id: 'services'},
                {text: 'Contact Us', selected: false, id: 'contact'}
            ]
        };
    }

    handleResize() {
        this.setState({windowWidth: window.innerWidth});
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize.bind(this));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize.bind(this));
    }

    toggleMenuOnClick() {
        if (this.state.mobileNavVisible) {
            this.setState({...this.state, mobileNavVisible: false});
        }
        else {
            this.setState({...this.state, mobileNavVisible: true});
        }
    }

    renderMobileHeader() {
        const navItemsMappedBurger = this.state.navItems.map(item => <MenuItemBurger text={item.text} id={item.id} onClick={() => this.toggleMenuOnClick()}/>);

        if (this.state.mobileNavVisible) {
            return (
                <div className="mobileHeader">
                    <div style={this.headerStyle}>
                        <Logo logo={logo}/>
                        <i className="fa fa-bars fa-2x" onClick={() => this.toggleMenuOnClick()} style={this.burgerMenuIconStyle}></i>
                    </div>
                    <hr></hr>
                    <div className="navItems" style={this.mobileMenuStyle}> {navItemsMappedBurger} </div>
                </div>
            )
        }

        return (
            <div className="mobileHeader">
                <div style={this.headerStyle}>
                    <Logo logo={logo}/>
                    <i className="fa fa-bars fa-2x" onClick={() => this.toggleMenuOnClick()} style={this.burgerMenuIconStyle}></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    renderWideHeader() {
        const navItemsMapped = this.state.navItems.map(item => <MenuItem text={item.text} id={item.id}/>);
        return (
            <div className="wideHeader" style={this.headerStyle}>
                <Logo logo={logo}/>
                <div className="navItems">{navItemsMapped}</div>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.windowWidth < 1000) {
            return (
                this.renderMobileHeader()
            )
        }
        return (
            this.renderWideHeader()
        );
    }

};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add a container to deal with the fixed position.

Something like this:

```
this.fixedHeader = {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

const FixedHeader = (children) => {
    return <div style={this.fixedHeader}>{children}</div>
}


render() {
    if (this.state.windowWidth < 1000) {
        return <FixedHeader>{ this.renderMobileHeader() }</FixedHeader>
    }
    return <FixedHeader>{ this.renderWideHeader() }</FixedHeader>
}
```

Comment: I wrapped the header in another div with the styling you've mentioned above

Comment: But the problem is, when I display the mobile menu, the height of the header doesn't adjust even though I've set height: auto.

Comment: Any ideas on how to fix that? Thanks :)

Comment: Hummm... I don't know exactly how it's your layout and what .navItems is setting... will the menu be listed after the header and needs to look as it inside header?

Comment: Hey, never, mind, it was just a styling issue. I needed to apply to correct style depending on whether menu was open or not. Thanks a lot for your help.